# C# Dictionary to Kendo DataSource

Tags: c#, json, kendo-ui

I'm not sure if this is possible but I figured I would ask to see if anyone has done this before.

I have a Dictionary of States containing the abbreviation and full name for the 50 States in America. What I would like to do is load this dictionary into a Kendo DataSource that I can use with a Kendo Dropdown. However, I can't figure out the correct way of going about this.

I have tried converting it to a JSON string and loading it that way but Kendo gets confused and doesn't know what exactly it's loading.

Here is my dictionary:

```
 public static Dictionary<string, string> USStates
    {
        get
        {
            var states = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            states.Add("AL", "Alabama");
            states.Add("AK", "Alaska");
            states.Add("AZ", "Arizona");
            states.Add("AR", "Arkansas");
            states.Add("CA", "California");
            states.Add("CO", "Colorado");
            states.Add("CT", "Connecticut");
            states.Add("DE", "Delaware");
            states.Add("FL", "Florida");
            states.Add("GA", "Georgia");
            states.Add("HI", "Hawaii");
            states.Add("ID", "Idaho");
            states.Add("IL", "Illinois");
            states.Add("IN", "Indiana");
            states.Add("IA", "Iowa");
            states.Add("KS", "Kansas");
            states.Add("KY", "Kentucky");
            states.Add("LA", "Louisiana");
            states.Add("ME", "Maine");
            states.Add("MD", "Maryland");
            states.Add("MA", "Massachusetts");
            states.Add("MI", "Michigan");
            states.Add("MN", "Minnesota");
            states.Add("MS", "Mississippi");
            states.Add("MO", "Missouri");
            states.Add("MT", "Montana");
            states.Add("NE", "Nebraska");
            states.Add("NV", "Nevada");
            states.Add("NH", "New Hampshire");
            states.Add("NJ", "New Jersey");
            states.Add("NM", "New Mexico");
            states.Add("NY", "New York");
            states.Add("NC", "North Carolina");
            states.Add("ND", "North Dakota");
            states.Add("OH", "Ohio");
            states.Add("OK", "Oklahoma");
            states.Add("OR", "Oregon");
            states.Add("PA", "Pennsylvania");
            states.Add("RI", "Rhode Island");
            states.Add("SC", "South Carolina");
            states.Add("SD", "South Dakota");
            states.Add("TN", "Tennessee");
            states.Add("TX", "Texas");
            states.Add("UT", "Utah");
            states.Add("VT", "Vermont");
            states.Add("VA", "Virginia");
            states.Add("WA", "Washington");
            states.Add("WI", "Wisconsin");
            states.Add("WY", "Wyoming");

            return states;
        }
    }
```

Returning the states as a Json Result:

```
public JsonResult GetStates()
{
    var states = States.USStates;
    return Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Attempting to load them into a Kendo Dropdown:

```
    function stateFilter(element) {
    element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Key",
        dataValueField: "Value",
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Admin/Company/GetStates",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        }),
        optionLabel: "-- Select Value --"
    });
}
```

I think the problem is coming from where I tell Kendo what it should look at for the text and value of the item.

When I try and do it this way I get the error of

> Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function in kendo.all.min.js:11

Here is a partial result of what the Json looks like that's returned:

```
{"AL":"Alabama","AK":"Alaska","AZ":"Arizona","AR":"Arkansas"}
```

Any guidance in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: is the JSON from /admin/company/getstates formatted well? what does that response look like? Use postman or similar.

Comment: @JonR. I added a code snippit to the post of what my JSON looks like

Comment: well that result would be one object with properties AL, AK, AZ, AR, none with names Value or Key. I would expect to see a result like: 

[{"key":"AL", "value":"Alabama"}, 
{"key":"AK", "value":"Alaska"}]

An array of objects with properties key and value

Comment: @JonR. How would I go about doing that? Sorry, I'm still new to it all and trying to understand it. Could I still use a dictionary for this or would I need to use something else?

Comment: You could map the result you are getting back from the server, you would still read from the same source, just process the response before using it in the datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all u need is:

```
return Json(states.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

`states.ToList()` convert to `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`, and KeyValuePair have properties Key and Value

Answer (score 0):

Based on some other reading about returning Dictionaries from C# it would be something like this.

```
string jsonString = "[";
foreach(var item in State.USStates)
{
    jsonString += string.Format("{"\key\":\"{0}\",\"value\":\"{1}\"},",item.Key,item.Value);
}
jsonString += "]";
return Json(jsonString,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```